# Random Broken Links

Tags: joomla-3.x

We are having a problem with passfaster.org, a driving instructor web site.

Every so often, various link stops working when clicked on from the home page. To resolve this, I have cleared the site cache, checked in all items and purge the expired cache. It could be that just one of these fixes the problem, I haven't had a chance to dig deeper yet as I have to wait for it to stop working before I can try something new.

When clicked on, instead of taking you to the correct page of the site visitors are taken to www.passfaster.org/index.php?width=1280&height=800

Does anyone know why this stops working every so often?

Kind regards

James

Answer (score 1):

Its not the cache issue, rather a small javascript code in your page is redirecting it to the above mentioned url. Here is the code that is causing the issue:

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "/index.php?width="+screen.width+"&height="+screen.height;</script>
```

Comment: Hi Nagarjun,

Thanks for that. I've had a look but I can't seem to find it. Can you see from your end, where this is being loaded from?

Kind regards

Comment: Think I've just found it. The following code was located in the template.php file:

if(isset($_SESSION['screen_width']) AND isset($_SESSION['screen_height'])){
} else if(isset($_REQUEST['width']) AND isset($_REQUEST['height'])) {
    $_SESSION['screen_width'] = $_REQUEST['width'];
    $_SESSION['screen_height'] = $_REQUEST['height'];
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
} else {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?width="+screen.width+"&height="+screen.height;</script>';
}